# select rows for a given value from file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read through a data file and only select/print rows where the value of a particular column is greater than e.g. 20. I have included my 'test' code. (I can get it to work if i specify the values, as shown in the commented 'a=...', but not when reading from the file).

```
import numpy as np

a = open('data_file.dat', 'r')

#a=[432,2,34,542]

header0 = a.readline()

x=[]
y=[]
z=[]

for line in a:
        line = line.strip()
        columns = line.split()
        x=columns[0]
        y=columns[1]
        z=columns[2] 


        if (x > 20 for x in a):
            print x
```

Comment: what does the file look like?

Answer (score 0):

You're close I think. I'm really not even sure what that last if statement is going to be doing, but it looks like a list comprehension mixed with an if, also mixed with the fact that you're reassigning x (if that statement actually worked...).  Try something like this:

```
for line in a:
    columns = line.strip().split()
    if columns[0] > 20:
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem might be the last two lines.

```
for line in a:
    ...
    if (x > 20 for x in a): # a is being consumed entirely here, which isn't what you want
        print x
```

The second `for __ in a` is reading through the whole file and only printing lines if the first row and first column of data is greater than 20. Just check for

```
if x > 20:
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I now however have a new problem! I am using

Comment: @SarahDavis I think you got cut off?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the line `if (x > 20 for x in a)` doesn't make any sense. This will always be true, since it creates a generator object.

What you want is simply: `if int(x) > 20:`. Notice, that you first have to convert `x` to an integer, since it is a string.

So if you have the file `data.dat`, which looks like:

```
col1 col2 col3
10 5 2
59 24 8
18 199 -0
```

Then you can read it with

```
f = open('data.dat', 'r')
header = f.readline()

for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()

    x=columns[0]
    y=columns[1]
    z=columns[2]

    if int(x) > 20:
        print columns
```

Additional note: if all your values are integer, you could convert them on very quickly with `map(int,...)`. Like

```
for line in f:
    columns = map(int, line.strip().split())
    if columns[0] > 20:
        print columns
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I am now able to read values, however it is only printing the final row (selected columns), rather than all rows with the column condition x>20 - any ideas?

Comment: @SarahDavis Can you give an example. The code above prints all rows with the desired condition. I'm not really sure what your problem is.